# Images exceeding size

Tags: html, css, angular, image

I want to display images in my div. I display different images according to the condition (if moviePoster true). 
I moviePoster I display it, but if it is false, I display a image that informed that the file is not found.
I don't know why but when I display these 2 types of image, the moviePoster image, exceeding the size of the dive.

[image: 1]

This is a screen from the issue in my application
[image: 2]

[image: 3]

```css
.list {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  margin: 30px;
  height: 230px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 12px #555;
}

.list-img {
  // border: 5px solid red;
  width: 20%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-img">
        <div *ngIf="moviePoster; else notFound">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w200/{{moviePoster}}" alt="...">
        </div>
        <ng-template #notFound>
            <img src="../../assets/not_found.jpg" alt="...">
        </ng-template>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you can include the actual code instead of images of code in your question

Comment: Can you put code rather than image please?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you want :

if the image is null then the default background will show.

**UPDATE**: i have made it more dynamic

```css
.list {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.list-item {
    height: 150px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}

.list-item + .list-item {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.list-img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    transition: background .5s ease;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-image: url(https://www.tourismselangor.my/wp-content/themes/Directory/images/noimage.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="list-img" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200)"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="list-img"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="list-item">
        <div class="list-img" style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200)"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

img is a default display: inline, so height and width refers to inner content.
Anyway set image width and height usually stretches image, and that's orrible.

I suggest on using a div with the image setted as background, so use something like that:

html:

```html
...
<div 
     *ngif="..." 
     class="thumbnail"
     style="background-image: url(https://...{{ moviePoster }})"
></div>
...
```

css:

```css
.thumbnail{
     background-size: cover;
     background-position: center;
}
```

You should apply this class also to #notFound.

One thing missing: thumbnail div must have height and width expressed
You can do that in multiple ways via css, depending on how have you structured the card box.

Hope it helps.